# Why doesn't this regex capture group stop with the set condition and continue capturing until the end of the line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, regex-group

```py
import re

input_text = "((PL_ADVB)alrededor (NOUN)(del auto rojizo, algo grande y completamente veloz)). Luego dentro del baúl rápidamente abajo de una caja por sobre ello vimos una caña." #example input

#place_reference = r"((?i:\w\s*)+)?"
#place_reference = r"(?i:[\w,;.]\s*)+" <--- greedy regex
place_reference = r"(?i:[\w,;.]\s*)+?"


list_all_adverbs_of_place = ["adentro", "dentro", "al rededor", "alrededor", "abajo", "hacía", "hacia", "por sobre", "sobre"]
list_limiting_elements = list_all_adverbs_of_place + ["vimos", "hemos visto", "encontramos", "hemos encontrado", "rápidamente", "rapidamente", "intensamente", "durante", "luego", "ahora", ".", ":", ";", ",", "(", ")", "[", "]", "¿", "?", "¡", "!", "&", "="]

pattern = re.compile(rf"(?:(?<=\s)|^)({'|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in list_all_adverbs_of_place)})?(\s+{place_reference})\s*({'|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in list_limiting_elements)})", flags = re.IGNORECASE)

input_text = re.sub(pattern,
                    #lambda m: f"((PL_ADVB){m[1]}{m[2]}){m[3]}",
                    lambda m: f"((PL_ADVB){m[1]}{m[2]}){m[3]}" if m[2] else f"((PL_ADVB){m[1]} NO_DATA){m[3]}",
                    input_text)

print(repr(input_text)) #--> output
```

When I use `lambda m: f"((PL_ADVB){m[1]}{m[2]}){m[3]}" if m[2] else f"((PL_ADVB){m[1]} NO_DATA){m[3]}"` I get this wrong output:

`'((PL_ADVB)alrededor (NOUN)(del auto rojizo, algo grande y completamente veloz)). Luego ((PL_ADVB)dentro del baúl rápidamente abajo de una caja por sobre ello vimos una caña).'`

It can be noticed how the capture group `{m[3]}` only captured `.`

That would not be entirely correct since you should not put everything inside the parentheses, in order to get this correct output:

```
"((PL_ADVB)alrededor ((NOUN)del auto rojizo, algo grande y completamente veloz)). Luego ((PL_ADVB)dentro del baúl) rápidamente ((PL_ADVB)abajo de una caja) ((PL_ADVB)por sobre ello) vimos una caña."
```

`list_all_adverbs_of_place` represents the start of the capturing group, and `list_limiting_elements` represents the end of the capturing group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understand your question correctly, the issue is the text "por sobre ello" is not highlighted by the regular expression.

The regular expression is trying to find a word from the first list, followed by the word we are interested in, followed by a word on the third list.

If we run your example, here is the matches it makes for the text given:

```py
input_text = "((PL_ADVB)alrededor (NOUN)(del auto rojizo, algo grande y completamente veloz)). Luego dentro del baúl rápidamente abajo de una caja por sobre ello vimos una caña."

list_all_adverbs_of_place = [
    "adentro",
    "dentro",
    "al rededor",
    "alrededor",
    "abajo",
    "hacía",
    "hacia",
    "por sobre",
    "sobre"]

list_limiting_elements = list_all_adverbs_of_place + [
    "vimos",
    "hemos visto",
    "encontramos",
    "hemos encontrado",
    "rápidamente", "rapidamente",
    "intensamente",
    "durante",
    "luego",
    "ahora", ".", ":", ";", ",", "(", ")", "[", "]", "¿", "?", "¡", "!", "&", "="]

# For the sake of this question, this could all be simplified
pattern = re.compile(
    rf"(?:(?<=\s)|^)({'|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in list_all_adverbs_of_place)})?(\s+{place_reference})\s*({'|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in list_limiting_elements)})", flags = re.IGNORECASE)


for match in pattern.finditer(input_text):
    print(match.group(1, 2, 3))
```

This shows the results:

```
('dentro', ' del baúl ', 'rápidamente')
('abajo', ' de una caja ', 'por sobre')
```

And running your code above gives the output

```
'((PL_ADVB)alrededor (NOUN)(del auto rojizo, algo grande y completamente veloz)). Luego ((PL_ADVB)dentro del baúl )rápidamente ((PL_ADVB)abajo de una caja )por sobre ello vimos una caña.'
```

However, "sobre ello vimos" is not wrapped in parenthesis, as you want.

If we take this output and feed it in again, the regular expression does now match and see this.

```py
for match in pattern.finditer(input_text):
    print(match.group(1, 2, 3))
```

```
('sobre', ' ello ', 'vimos')
```

The issue is "sobre" was the word in the previous match, and that caused it to be missed. This can be fixed by making the third word be specified in a look-ahead assertion.

You can take the third word regular expression

`(third|list|of|words)`

and wrap it in a `(?=...)` statement.
`(?=(third|list|of|words))`

So that would make the final regular expression:

```py
pattern = re.compile(
    rf"(?:(?<=\s)|^)({'|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in list_all_adverbs_of_place)})?(\s+{place_reference})\s*((?={'|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in list_limiting_elements)}))", flags = re.IGNORECASE)
```